# Django app not recognizing template views on Heroku

Tags: django, templates, heroku

I'm working on a Django app that deploys to Heroku.

Following the Django tutorial (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial02/) and trying to change the base_site.html for the admin page from the template Django view to a customized view file.

I changed the settings file to point to the templates folder, per the directions.

When run locally, there is no problem.

When I deploy to Heroku, it is using the customized base_site.html view page because I see the custom text I incorporated but it is just plain HTML when rendered, no formatting or styling, as if it no longer picks up the base Django templates.

It looks like the base_site.html view inherits its formatting/styling from other pages that are in the default Django templates so it looks like it no longer sees those templates in deployment on Heroku.

This changed when I adjusted the settings to point to the templates because these pages previously styled correctly when using the defaults view pages.

Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Here are the template settings I am using in case that helps:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This link on the Heroku site solved it.  Make sure to include whitenoise in your settings and in wsgi.py.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets